# Variable Function: Sum elements of List

Tags: scala

Why Line 1 and 2 works, **but 3 fail** ?¿:

```
val sum1= (a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) => a + b + c   //OK
List(1,2,3).reduceLeft(_+_)    //OK

val sum2 =(x: List) =>x.reduceLeft(_+_)    //Fail
```

Comment: You should add the element type to `x: List`, so it becomes `List[Int]` or `List[Double]` or whatever you need.

Comment: **Yes**, thanks, you are in True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the element type to `x: List`, so it becomes `List[Int]` or `List[Double]`. `List` itself is a `raw type`, which is illegal in Scala. Without the type annotation, the compiler also does not know what the `+` operator means in the `reduceLeft(_+_)` part, so it has to produce an error.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is missing proof that the underlying objects inside `List` are a type that defines the `+` operator. Here's a nice way to use the underlying Scala lib to define a method that is capable of adding a List of any numerical type.

For this, you don't even need `reduce`, as Scala already defines `sum`. `List` is a higher kinded type construcotr, more details [here](http://adriaanm.github.io/research/2010/10/06/new-in-scala-2.8-type-constructor-inference/).

`def addList[T : Numeric](list: List[T]): T = list.sum`